# What's the reason for the below code output in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

```
for (var a=0; a<5; a++)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(a);
    }, 0);
}
```

The above code in javascript is prompting me with the output of 5, 5 times infact my expectation was of the output something like 0,1,2,3,4 but rather it shows me the output of 5,5,5,5,5. Why is it so?

Besides that please explain me the concept of **context and scope** in javascript i always fail to understand it through many examples reading from the web.

Comment: Why you are using setTimeout function???

Comment: I was just brushing my concept of js but infact i landed doing this and now trouble understanding it :)

Comment: I know this question has been asked many times before.  Have you searched for an answer?

Comment: short answer: `a` is closed over in the callback and the loop finishes before the first time the callback function executes.

Comment: @DavinTryon, apologize i haven't searched because i was not aware what topic to search on google

Comment: javascript is not a line by line programming language

Comment: Scope in ES5 is extremely simple: all variables are scoped to their containing function. ES6 introduces new kinds of variables (`let` vs `var`) that are scoped to the block.

Comment: @DavinTryon i have put the timeout to **0** still why it is showing me 5,5,5,5,5

Comment: As JavaScript is monothreaded, asynchronous timers like setTimeout() can't run immediately, even with a timeout value of 0.

In fact, it's in the HTML 5 Spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) that timers should wait at least 4 ms before being executed.

So in your case, the loop has ended before the first call to the alert() function is made.

Comment: @HarshSharma same reason. Read about the JavaScript event loop.

Comment: Thanks @noKid appreciated

Comment: **`setTimeout()` with 0 will only run when the stack is empty.** So when the `for` loop is finished and the stack is empty the 5 `setTimeout()` callbacks are being called and `a` is already 5 by then.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `setTimeout()`, your  `alert()` is called asynchronously so it is very likely that `for` loop is already finish before `alert()` get executed.